# ScrollView with LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll

I put him in one of my ScrollView LinearLayout and it works but the problem is that the names of the buttons do not see them anymore as if the buttons were huge.

This is the XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bg"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Graph10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:scrollbars="vertical" 
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sfondo">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Graph"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="950sp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LL2"
    android:layout_width="950sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="85"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bConnect"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connect"
        android:textSize="14dp"             
        style="@style/btnStyleBeige" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bDisconnect"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Disconnect"
        android:textSize="14dp" 

        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LLY"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100" >

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/bFreeze"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Freeze"
        android:textSize="14sp" 

        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAbsolute"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Absolute"
        android:textSize="14sp" 

        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"

        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/bRelative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Relative"
        android:textSize="14sp" 

        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/bPoc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="P.O.C."
        android:textSize="14sp" 

        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />  

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" 
        android:background="@drawable/rotondo">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Ch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="• TA DX:  "

            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Valore1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="0 µV"

            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Label2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" 
        android:background="@drawable/rotondo">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Ch2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="• TA DX:  "

            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Valore2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="0 µV"

            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Label3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" 
        android:background="@drawable/rotondo">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Ch3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="• TA DX:  "

            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Valore3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="0 µV"

            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Label4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" 
        android:background="@drawable/rotondo">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Ch4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="• TA DX:  "

            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Valore4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="0 µV"

            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Label5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" 
        android:background="@drawable/rotondo">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Poc1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="• TA P.O.C.: "
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ValorePoc1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="0 %"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Label6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" 
        android:background="@drawable/rotondo">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Poc2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="• MM P.O.C.: "
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ValorePoc2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="0 %"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

you can tell me where am I wrong? I can not find the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First change height of `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content`. Apply some fixed height to your `Button's`.

Comment: but in this way the buttons do not occupy the space of 950sp

Comment: When you put your any UI element in `ScrollView` it height must be `wrap_content` always or you can apply it to fixed.

Comment: but my problem is the width

Comment: @PG_Android do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Change `fill_parent` to `wrap_content` for the button width.

Comment: but in this way the buttons do not occupy the space of 950sp

Answer (score 0):

Add weight management:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LL2"
    android:layout_width="950sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="85"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bConnect"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Connect"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"  />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bDisconnect"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Disconnect"
    android:textSize="14dp" 
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
```

Bon courage!